# Python generator object getting modified after being saved

Tags: python

I'm iterating through and want to save generator objects as I go along.

In the example below, I want the variable "gen" (the generator returned) to return "Tom" and "Tommy", but I find that when I mutate the original list the generator was called on, it also changes my generator object.

Desired behavior would be to save these generator objects as I go along, without having them being modified.

I understand that a list is mutable, but if this was run with a function, it would save the output to the variable, and that output could NOT be changed.

(for more context, I'm building a dictionary of generators where point-in-time matters, I chose a generator because the computation is pretty heavy and want to save it until the end)

```
# simple class
class Name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# simple generator
def generator_function(lst):
    for obj in lst:
        yield obj.name

lst = [Name("Tom"), Name("Tommy")]

# create gen object
gen= generator_function(lst)


# mutate list
lst[0] = Name("Andrea")


# >>> Prints out :    "Andrea" , "Tommy"  
# >>> Desired output: "Tom", "Tommy"
for ii in gen:
    print(ii)
```

Comment: The `lst` passed to `generator_function` references the very same `lst` that has been mutated.  If you want a distinct list that won't be affected by modification you will need to make a copy for use within the `generator_function`.

Comment: You should make a copy of the list, e.g `gen= generator_function(list(lst))`

Comment: Seeing your edit, the behavior you might be wanting may be "copy-on-write", but this is not something default to Python's basic data structures.

Comment: @metatoaster can you elaborate ? I've been trying to make deep copies of the list but it doesnt work. what's copy-on-write

Comment: [Wikipedia entry for Copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). As this is Python you basically should be building a new/intermediate list for anything your code may currently be iterating through, otherwise unexpected behavior will result (such as what you've seen, or loop that never end because the length of the list being iterated over have changed).

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, python lists are variable. Therefore, you will have to make a new copy for every generator you create.

This can be achieved easily by modifying your call to `generator_function`:

```
gen = generator_function(list(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally crazy about hoping the user remembers to copy their list when passing to the generator. In this case, you can return a generator expression:

```py
from typing import List, Iterable

def generator_function(lst: List[Name]) -> Iterable[str]:
    return (obj.name for obj in lst.copy())
```

I've also added annotations since I think it's important, especially here where your generator is accessing a `.name` property.