# Copied list passed to generator reflects changes made to original

Tags: python, generator

In answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266660) question, I stumbled across some unexpected behavior:

```py
from typing import List, Iterable


class Name:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name


def generator(lst: List[Name]) -> Iterable[str]:
    lst_copy = lst.copy()
    for obj in lst_copy:
        yield obj.name
```

When modifying the list that is passed to the generator, even though a copy is made, changes to the original list are still reflected:

```py
lst = [Name("Tom"), Name("Tommy")]
gen = generator(lst)
lst[0] = Name("Andrea")
for name in gen:
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
Andrea
Tommy
```

Simply returning a generator expression works as expected:

```py
def generator(lst: List[Name]) -> Iterable[str]:
    return (obj.name for obj in lst.copy())
```

Output:

```
Tom
Tommy
```

Why doesn't the `lst.copy()` in the first generator function work as expected?

Comment: `lst.copy()` isn't executed until the first `next()` is called.

Comment: Wombatz is right! It's enough to insert a print() before or after the copy() to verify it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior is best understood with the addition of some extra print statements:

```py
def generator(lst: List[Name]) -> Iterable[str]:
    print("Creating list copy...")
    lst_copy = lst.copy()
    print("Created list copy!")
    for obj in lst_copy:
        yield obj.name
        
lst = [Name("Tom"), Name("Tommy")]
print("Starting assignment...")
gen = generator(lst)
print("Assignment complete!")

print("Modifying list...")
lst[0] = Name("Andrea")
print("Modification complete!")

for name in gen:
    print(name)
```

Notice that the copy does not happen at assignment time -- it happens *after* the list is modified!

```
Starting assignment...
Assignment complete!
Modifying list...
Modification complete!
Creating list copy...
Created list copy!
Andrea
Tommy
```

*Nothing* in the generator's body is executed until the `for` loop attempts to extract an element. Since this extraction attempt occurs after the list is mutated, the mutation is reflected in the results from the generator.

Comment: That's really strange/unintuitive behavior. I would've expected the body of the generator function to run at least until the first `yield` is seen, but I guess that would run counter to laziness. Still, I would expect at least the set-up code to run right away so that potentially expensive "set-up" code doesn't penalize the user later when they start using their generator. I guess this is a pretty strange case, but I'm still surprised. I use generators all the time, so I'm pretty surprised to have learned something new about them today :D

Comment: Also, lol I think a single print statement inside the generator would suffice :D

Comment: @ddejohn: If you want that kind of behavior, write a non-generator function that performs setup eagerly and *then* calls a generator function. Generators aren't designed under the assumption that there will be heavy setup work, or that you *want* expensive setup to happen eagerly.

Comment: Yeah, this was more just me being somewhat surprised that the entire body of the generator function isn't executed until `next()`. I've never needed this functionality so I'd never thought about it before, and was surprised.

Answer (score 2):

The body of a generator does not start executing until the first item is requested. So in this code:

```
def generator(lst: List[Name]) -> Iterable[str]:
    lst_copy = lst.copy()
    for obj in lst_copy:
        yield obj.name

lst = [Name("Tom"), Name("Tommy")]
gen = generator(lst)
lst[0] = Name("Andrea")
for name in gen:
    print(name)
```

... First, the `lst[0] = Name("Andrea")` is executed. Then, you have a `for` loop, which starts executing the generator. That's when `lst_copy = lst.copy()` is executed, which is too late to get in before the `lst[0]` assignment.

The generator expression works, because the iterable portion of the generator (`lst.copy()`, the last part) must be evaluated before creating the iterator.

Comment: Great answer for not only explaining why the first example doesn't work, but why the second example *does*.